# I'm Creating Project using retrofit but it's force close when run

Tags: android

Here is the code of my main activity.

I use Retrofit to call data from movie database API, but wheni run it, it's installed but force close.  i wonder in which part the error, this is the code of my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView mrecyclerview;
    List<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mrecyclerview= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(resultList);
        mrecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,2));
        new RequestMovie().execute("popular");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       if (item.getItemId()== R.id.action_popular){
           new RequestMovie().execute("popular");
       } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.action_top_rated){
           new RequestMovie().execute("top_rated");
       }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class RequestMovie extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String kategori = params[0];
            if (kategori.equals("popular")){
                ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit()
                        .create(ApiInterface.class);
                Call <EldarMovie> call = apiInterface.getPopular();
                call.enqueue(new Callback<EldarMovie>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<EldarMovie> call, Response<EldarMovie> response) {
                        EldarMovie movie=response.body();
                        adapter.setData(movie.getResults());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<EldarMovie> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });


            } 
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is anything wrong from the code which my make my app force close?

Comment: first of all, why are you using asyncTask, The retrofit use threads itself and you don't need asynctask

Comment: Please add your crash log in question

Comment: add logcat report and why are you using asyncTask

Answer (score 0):

If you are using enqueue with the response and failure callback with Retrofit, then no need to put it in an AsyncTask because they are already asynchronous.

You can refer here [Call method in Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html).

Please if it crashed, take a look at the LogCat and post it here. It is better to trace the error with the LogCat.